# Get List operation using Netsuite connector in Mule 4

Tags: netsuite, mulesoft, mule4

I am unable to frame the required input to get list operation for Netsuite connector in Mule 4.Tried below but didn't work.

```
[
{
     name: "checking",
    "type": "customer",
    internalId: 12345678
} as Object {
    class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.BaseRef"
}
]
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    {
         "type":"CUSTOMER",
         "internalId": "112654",
         "externalId":"customer",
    }as Object  {class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.RecordRef"},
    {
         "type":"CUSTOMER",
         "internalId": "173419",
         "externalId":"customer",
    }as Object  {class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.RecordRef"},
    {
         "type":"CUSTOMER",
         "internalId": "174329",
         "externalId":"customer",
    }as Object  {class : "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.RecordRef"},
    
]
```